# Plesk database - ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2008, plesk

I'm having an issue with my Plesk installation. When I attempt to manage my database it says "The server is unavailable". When I try to create a new database it gives the following error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it

I've already tried restarting the Plesk SQL service. I've also tried repairing Plesk via the command line tool but it gives the same error.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Or where I can find more logs to get a more specific error?

Comment: Try to change your database port to `33060` or to `8889`

Comment: @groovy_guy I can't even create a database, it just gives the error above.